# External library with no jar file

Tags: android, eclipse, java

I downloaded a package ([Jep Java 2.4.1 GPL](http://www.singularsys.com/jep/download-trial.php)) but it doesn't come with a jar file as described in the [documentation](http://www.singularsys.com/jep/doc/html/usage.html). It's a zip file, and when extracted it has these folders:

[image]

How do I get this working in Eclipse for an Android project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have it in mine.
It's inside `dist`.

[image]

Comment: i just wanted to attach a picture.. it's also fine even if my answer is not accepted..

Comment: @RobbyPond - this does appear to be effectively an answer, as it is pointing out that version *with* a jar file is available.

Answer (score 1):

you can get the `.jar` located inside the `/bin` or `/dist` folder.

The `jep-2.4.1.jar` of the release [`Jep Java 2.4.1 GPL`](http://www.singularsys.com/download/jep-2.4.1-ext-1.1.1-gpl.zip) is located in `/dist` folder.